# How to get the partial text of class value that is inside a tag

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to fetch the text 'completed' from the below html element

```
<div class="status">
      <span class="statusText completed"></span>
</div>

xpath: //span[@class='statusText completed']
```

based on the status -- 'completed' , 'inprogress' or 'error' I want to proceed further.
Please help me with this.

Note: There is no text for span element to retreive using 'getText()' method.

Comment: In JavaScript you'd use `theSpanElement.classList.contains("completed")`. You also tagged this with Java and Selenium, please provide context and code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getAttribute()` and get the class attribute value and then spilt it to get the last string value.

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'statusText')]"));
String[] strele = element.getAttribute("class").split(" ");
String status = strele[strele.length-1];
System.out.println(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='status']")).getText();
status= status.split(" ")[1];
```